# React, how to make the component name used dynamic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I have a wrapper that populates the `isScrolled` --- When the page loads isScrolled is `false`, when the user scrolls, isScrolled is equal to `true`.

In one of my React components, I have have the following:

```
    <Button.Secondary
      size="S"
      onClick={() => {
       // lots of stuff here
      }}
    >
      {!isLoggedIn ? 'XXXXX' : 'YYYY'}
    </Button.Secondary>
```

The challenge I'm having is when isScrolled is false, I want the above `Button.Secondary` - When isScrolled is true, I want:

```
    <Button.Secondary
      size="S"
      onClick={() => {
       // lots of stuff here
      }}
    >
      {!isLoggedIn ? 'XXXXX' : 'YYYY'}
    </Button.Secondary>
```

How can I make the `Button._____` dynamic based on the isScrolled property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretend your `Button` that you import is just an object that looks like this:

```
const Button = {
    Primary: () => return some jsx
    Secondary: () => return some jsx
}
```

So if you want to render the secondary button you can do:

```
  <Button.Secondary>

  // or
  const Cmp = Button.Secondary;
  return <Cmp/>

  // or
  const Cmp = Button['Secondary'];
  return <Cmp/>
```

extrapolating:

```
import { Button } from 'somewhere'


const YourCmp = ({isScrolled}) => {

   const Cmp = Button[isScrolled ? 'Secondary' : 'Primary'];
   return <Cmp {...yourProps}><SomeChild/></Cmp>

}
```

Comment: This way is a correct way but it is not readable enough.

Comment: @AmerllicA you don't have to write this exact code, you can write it however you choose to. The only point of this was to illustrate "how" to render a component dynamically - interesting a correct answer got downvoted.

Comment: Dear @Adam, Exactly you right, I just offer a better way, just like I said your code works well but it is not readable enough. just it. thanks for your comment bro.

Answer (score 1):

For such cases, the below way is a way to handle this situation:

```
~~~
const { isScrolled } = this.state;

const Btn = isScrolled ? Button.Secondary : Button.Primary;

~~~

<Btn
  size="S"
  onClick={() => {
    // lots of stuff here
  }}
>
  {!isLoggedIn ? 'XXXXX' : 'YYYY'}
</Btn>
```

Comment: Dear @Adam Bro, I used this way on my project, It is more readable. just it. both answers work well. But when code can be simple and understandable why not we obey it?

Answer (score 1):

you can build an object with a helper function or pass it in as props

then dynamically render it however you want.

so ex:

```
import all your potential buttons 

get someLogicRelatedToScrollPosition(){
 ... take scroll position and return the name of key you want from the incoming prop

}

render(){
.... some code

/** this object might look like 
 *{
 * initial: Button.Primary,
 * scrolled: Button.Secondary,
 * someOtherScrollPosition: Button.Whatever
 * 
 *  *}
 */
const {myButtonsComponents} = this.props;
const CurrentButtonComponent = myButtonsComponents[this.someLogicRelatedToScrollPosition]


return (
  ..jsx
<CurrentButtonComponent {...props} />
)}
```